# How to run query on Apache Jackrabbit, explain with example

Tags: java, database, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

I am using Apache Jackrabbit as a database.

```
In my case, root node has numbers of child nodes(only at depth 1).
All child node has unique name, i.e., some Integer.
Each child Node have some properties that I have used further.
```

**My task**

I have to take top 10 nodes whose keys(integer values) are minimum.

**My thinking**

To achieve above goal, I make a query that sorts the keys of all child nodes, and pick top 10. Then by using that keys, I get all corresponding nodes, and after working, delete all that key/value pairs.

**For that I searched a lot on the internet how to run the query. Can you please tell me how to run query on apache jackrabit. It is good, if you explain with example.**

**Edit no. 1**

public class JackRabbit {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {

        Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
        javax.jcr.Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

        Node root = session.getRootNode();


        // Obtain the query manager for the session via the workspace ...
        javax.jcr.query.QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();

        // Create a query object ...
        String expression = "select * from nt:base where name= '12345' ";
        javax.jcr.query.Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);

        // Execute the query and get the results ...
        javax.jcr.query.QueryResult result = query.execute();


        session.logout();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Exception**

```
javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: Query:
select * from nt:(*)base where name= '12345'; expected: <end>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:69)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:51)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:45)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.RepositoryServiceImpl.executeQuery(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:2004)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.WorkspaceManager.executeQuery(WorkspaceManager.java:349)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.query.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:149)
    at jackrabbit.JackRabbit.main(JackRabbit.java:36)
```

**I want to write a query of below scenereo**

[image]

Here nodes having integer value have some properties. I want to sort these nodes by their integer values, and extract top 50 nodes for further processing.

Help me in that.

Answer (score 5):

You should quote your node type name in JCR-SQL2:

```sql
select * from [nt:base]
```

This is one of the main differences between [JCR-SQL](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/6.6.2_XPath_and_SQL.html) and [JCR-SQL2](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html). Besides, `name` is a [dynamic operand](http://www.h2database.com/jcr/grammar.html#dynamic_operand) taking a selector argument. So a better way to write your query would be this:

```sql
select * from [nt:base] as b where name(b) = '12345'
```

Comment: For me - using jackrabbit - `name(b)` will throw `javax.jcr.UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException` ... but using `localname(b)` works fine.

Comment: @kevinjansz: Huh, could be. It's been a while and I haven't really touched JCR, since... so I'm afraid I won't be of any help

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways of executing your queries depending on the [query language](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Query+languages) you want to use.

Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/ehsavoie/Silverpeas-Core/blob/master/lib-core/src/main/java/org/silverpeas/attachment/repository/DocumentRepository.java#L397) for some simple query using only the API and not SQL like string queries.
You can take a look at [JBoss Modeshape documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Query+languages) for examples too since it is another JCR 2.0 implementation.

Comment: I made one code, but it throws one error, that says Query is wrong. Please help me in making it correct. See edit no. 1

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you to execute the query:

```
public FolderListReturn listFolder(String parentNode, String userid,String password) {
    System.out.println("getting folders and files from = "+parentNode+" of user : "+userid);


    SessionWrapper sessions =JcrRepositoryUtils.login(userid, password);
    Session jcrsession = sessions.getSession();

    Assert.notNull(name);
    FolderListReturn folderList1 = new FolderListReturn();
    ArrayOfFolders folders = new ArrayOfFolders();
    try {
                javax.jcr.query.QueryManager queryManager;

                queryManager = jcrsession.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
                String expression = "select * from [nt:folder] AS s WHERE ISCHILDNODE(s,'"+name+"')and CONTAINS(s.[edms:owner],'*"+userid+"*')  ORDER BY s.["+Config.EDMS_Sorting_Parameter+"] ASC";

                javax.jcr.query.Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);
                javax.jcr.query.QueryResult result = query.execute();
                        for (NodeIterator nit = result.getNodes(); nit.hasNext();) {
                Node node = nit.nextNode();
                Folder folder = new Folder();
                folder=setProperties(node,folder,userid,password,jcrsession,name);
                folders.getFolderList().add(folder);
                }
        folderList1.setFolderListResult(folders);
        folderList1.setSuccess(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //JcrRepositoryUtils.logout(sessionId);
    }
    return folderList1;
}
```